# Git: How to list commits on this branch but not from merged branches

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-log

Suppose your git commit history looks like this:

```
A---B---C---D---E---F master
     \         /
      X---Y---Z topic
```

Is it possible to have git list only the commits on master, A-F? In other words, if the commit was on a merged-in branch, I don't want it show.

Comment: So, how would git know which of `D` and `Z` was part of the merged branch?

Comment: When merged from master, previous master commits are the first parents in merge. `git log` allows to display only those commits with `--first-parent`, so you get the right stuff

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do I run Git Log to see changes only for a specific branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649356/how-do-i-run-git-log-to-see-changes-only-for-a-specific-branch)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

`git log` has option `--first-parent`, so you won't get `topic` history.

When merged from `master`, the `master` commits are the first parents in merge. Git log allows to display only those commits with --first-parent, so you get the right stuff.

Comment: +1 `--first-parent` does it :) combined with `--no-merges` you can hide the merge commits

Comment: How to exit the long list?

Comment: @RuiMonteiro press Q

Answer (score 27):

*TLDR* : `git log origin/master --no-merges` will give you a log of master and exclude any merged commits ( in this case x, y, z )

**Original Points**

There is another general way to go about this that doesn't rely on `--first-parent` which will be helpful in certain situations.. using the branch exclusion filters

`git log origin/topic ^origin/master`  This will give you a log of `origin/topic` with all of `origin/master`'s commits removed.

you could also add in `--no-merges` which will hide merge commits which you may or may not want.

Another handy tip is to use `shortlog` instead of `log` which will give you more of an abbreivated summary that can be handy for release notes, or communication of whats in a branch.

**Update**
After re-reading this, you actually would want nearly the inverse of what I posted; however it would end up excluding everything that is on master and foo ( `git log origin/master ^origin/foo` ) .  However you could also get what you ask for ( hide all commits that are part of merges) with `git log origin/master --no-merges`

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Charles works for me.

```
git log has option --first-parent --no-merges, so you won't get topic history.
```

But If you are using any graphic user interface for your Git activities like, Git Extension, SourceTree, Tortoise Git,

Then there are direct options to check the first parent in your tools. I thought to add this answer to the list as most the people find Graphic Interface easy. and You can directly cherry pick all the commits from that particular branch from tool, if required.

I have attached the example of two tools, It would be similar for other tools as well: [I have blured the username, git repo name as this is a private repository, but still you can get an idea how to use first parent from tools]

1. Git Extension

   - Open Git Extension -> Checkout the feature branch you want to see the commits, there is a option to select first commits as shown in Image:

[image]

2. Tortoise Git

   - Open the repository folder -> Click on Show logs from Tortoise Git -> Checkout the branch and select first commits as shown in Image

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Does this not work?

```
git log master
git log --stat master
```

Comment: No those don't work.  The merge commit has two parents; everything tracking back from both of those parents is on the 'master' branch.