# Create fake commits from graph

Tags: git

Considering I have the following ASCII graph:

```
A---B---C---D---E---F master
     \         /
      X---Y---Z topic
```

(stolen from [a recent but unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248137))

Is there a command/script/tool which accepts this as input and creates the dummy commits accordingly?

Comment: +1 I was thinking the same when recreating the history of the previous question :)

Comment: Exactly this as input, or would a more machine-friendly format be acceptable?

Comment: Well, this is, I think, the git documentation standard, so it would be best if it could be parsed without further changes.

Comment: I don't know one, but it would be easy to split this task in two. Parse the graph, and from a graph generate appropriate commits. This way it would be even easier to have parsers for different versions of the graph (this one, and the one provided by git log --graph)

Comment: What are the file contents and metadata, such as timestamps and commit messages for each commit?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I cannot think of a reason to do it.  @Debilski ?

Comment: I wish all Git Tutorials or Scripts would provide a transcript for creating the test repo, or offer a public one to clone. Especially Git books should work within this example.

Answer (score 7):

[Okay, I'll bite...] No, there isn't.

[edit]  So you might ask "How can you answer 'no' - you can't prove a negative".  Well, if you can define the 'universe' and exhaustively search the 'universe' then you can prove a negative.  For my 'no' answer, I've defined the 'universe' as the set of git utilities provided as part of the git distribution.  If you define the 'universe' as 'all current and future git utilities' then the answer might not be 'no.'

Comment: This answer maybe has some inflated-depth, but it is correct to the question.

Comment: this answer made me laugh