# How do I get the Git log for a specific branch only?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-checkout, git-log

Assuming the following Git history:

```
Branch1     B---C-------F---G
           /     \           \
Master    A-------D---E-------H
```

Doing a *git log master* gives the log entries in following order **A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H.** - but I'm interested in history of master-only (i.e **A-D-E-H**)

How can I "get rid" of the unwanted log-entries from *Branch1*? I tried a lot of options for *git log*, but I cannot find anything appropriate...

---

This leads to a further thing I don't understand in this context:

Looking at the log-history given by *git log master* it shows how my branch master evolved (**A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H**).

But doing a *git checkout HEAD~1* (assuming master=HEAD) gives me **E** (Evolution *HEAD~3*:**A** - *HEAD~2*:**D** - *HEAD~1*:**E** - *HEAD*:**H** -> **A-D-E-H**)

This is what I don't understand: the ancestor of **H** looking at *git log* is **G**, while the ancestor of **H** looking at *git checkout* is **E**.

I don't understand this - What's the ancestor of **H**: **G** or **E**?...

---

**Conclusion**: What I would like to have are *git log* entries from *HEAD* to *HEAD~n* only (for example above n = 1...3).
How can this be achieved? Is it possible at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: How to list commits on this branch but not from merged branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248137/git-how-to-list-commits-on-this-branch-but-not-from-merged-branches)

Comment: You're right - had the wrong search keywords (and the quoted question is quite poorly tagged ...)

Comment: @hopprosch: I fixed the tags in the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do I run Git Log to see changes only for a specific branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649356/how-do-i-run-git-log-to-see-changes-only-for-a-specific-branch)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is

```
git log --first-parent
```

Why that option is called `--first-parent` answers your question

> I don't understand this - What's the ancestor of H: G or E?

The answer is: **both**. E is the *first parent*, but G is the *second parent*, because H is a merge commit. A merge commit is one that has more than one parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that was exactly I was looking for! I played with TortoiseGit - which has a "first-parent" option in the log-view. But this does not seem to work correctly in all cases (if "show all branches" is checked, "first_parent" does not show any effect ...) This led me away from "first parent" (TortoiseGit 1.7.14.0)

Comment: What's not completly clear, is nomenclature: why is the option called "--first-parent" (singular) while it gives the complete ancestor row of first degree? Should be better "--first-parents" IMHO

Comment: @hoppfrosch For each commit encountered, only the 'first parent' of that particular commit is chosen.  Commit H is a merge commit and so it has two parents (G and E), but the first parent is E.  So each time a merge commit is encountered, the only first parent is followed, thereby omitting the top branch entirely.