# Git: How to list commits on a merged branch?

Tags: git, merge, branch, history

This is the inverse of [how to list commits on a branch but not merged branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248137/git-how-to-list-commits-on-this-branch-but-not-from-merged-branches), so I'll ask it in the same format. Let's say my git commit history looks like this:

```
A---B---C---D---E---F master
     \         /
      X---Y---Z topic
```

How do I list the commits on the `topic` branch -- that is, `X`, `Y`, and `Z`? Note that simply doing `git log topic` won't work -- that will return commits `A` and `B` as well.

I had thought I could run `git merge-base topic master` to find `B`, and then do `git log B..Z` to get these commits. Unfortunately, `git merge-base topic master` returns `Z`, not `B`, which makes sense in retrospect -- since `Z` is already merged to master, the first commit between `topic` and `master` that shares history is `Z`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Git, show all commits that are in one branch, but not the other(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710894/using-git-show-all-commits-that-are-in-one-branch-but-not-the-others)

Answer (score 5):

If you only merged `topic` to `master` *once*, and you know that you merged `topic` into `master` in merge commit `E`, you can simply use the [`<rev>^-<n>` revision syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgt-ltngtemegemHEAD-HEAD-2em):

```
git log E^-
```

If you don't remember the hash of commit `E` and want an easy way to find it, based on the name of your branch (`topic`), you can use one of the answers in the question ["Find merge commit which include a specific commit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475448/find-merge-commit-which-include-a-specific-commit). I personnally like [`git when-merged`](https://github.com/mhagger/git-when-merged):

```
git when-merged topic
```

Putting it all together:

```
git log $(git when-merged -c topic)^-
```

---

If you merged `topic` several times to `master`, then the syntax above will only list the commits that were merged in the most recent merge commit. In that case, you can use rocketraman's [`mergedtopiclg` alias](https://gist.github.com/rocketraman/1fdc93feb30aa00f6f3a9d7d732102a9#file-gitconfig-L73-L75)

```
git mergedtopiclg $(git when-merged -c topic)
```

For completeness this alias is configured as

```sh
    mergedtopiclg = !sh -c \"git lg $(git oldest-ancestor $1^2 ${2:-master})..$1^2\" -
    # The oldest ancestor between an integration branch (by default, master) and a topic branch (by default HEAD)
    # e.g. git oldest-ancestor master ai/topic
    # See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4991675/430128
    oldest-ancestor = !bash -c 'diff --old-line-format= --new-line-format= <(git rev-list --first-parent \"${1:-master}\") <(git rev-list --first-parent \"${2:-HEAD}\") | head -1' -
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following command:

```
git log topic --not $(git rev-list master ^topic --merges | tail -1)^
```

`git rev-list master ^topic --merges` returns the SHA-1 keys for all merge commits from `master` to `topic`; since it's possible that there are multiple merge commits I use `tail -1` to just get the last merge commit which is the merge commit of `master` and `topic`.

Then we log all commits for `topic` while omiting all commits for the first parent of the merge commit (`--not <merge-commit>^`).

To use this command effectively I would define an alias as follows:

```
git config --global alias.<alias-name> '!f() { git log $1 --not $(git rev-list $2 ^$1 --merges | tail -1)^; }; f'
```

Which then can be used like this `git <alias-name> topic master`.

---

Just for your information:
In my git version (1.9.0) it would also work if you omit `tail` but I thought it would be cleaner to only return the relevant SHA-1 key.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all -- it gets me a lot of extra commits.

Comment: @singingwolfboy it works perfectly fine for me. Can you provide me with your in- and output?

Comment: @SaschaWolf Would it be a way to get same result without cloning repository?

Comment: @SunggukLim What exactly do you mean? Do you mean you want to perform this for a remote repository such as one on GitHub?