# How to list the commits of a branch which is now merged into main?

Tags: git, command-line-interface, git-commit, git-cherry-pick

I am looking to list all the commits that were merged to the main branch from feature branches:-

```
    |
    v
    main branch
    |
    a  
    | \ 
    b  y
    |  |
    c  x
    | / -> feature branch
    d
    |
```

Is it possible to list the commit x and y,
given the feature branch name and master main branch name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is :

1. spot commit `d`
2. get the list of commits `d..y`

---

To spot commit `d` when branches are already merged, you can use the following script :

```
#!/bin/bash

target=$1
if [ -z "$target" ]; then
    target=HEAD
fi

# get the 'first-parent' list of commits from main
# (the left most path in your graph)
git rev-list --first-parent main > /tmp/tmp-rev-list

# get the 'first-parent' list of commits from $target,
# and use grep to match them with the first-parent history of 'main'
base=$(git rev-list --first-parent "$target" | grep -F -f /tmp/tmp-rev-list | head -1)

rm /tmp/tmp-rev-list

echo $base
```

or the one liner :

```
base=$(git rev-list --first-parent [y] |\
    grep -Ff <(git rev-list --first-parent main) |\
    head -1)
```

You can then run :

```
git log --oneline --graph $base..[y]
```

---

*some explanations on why you need that:*

*Before* branches are merged, you can look for the so called merge base of two branches : `git merge-base main feature` or `git merge-base main y`. But *after* `feature` has been merged, this stops working -- since `feature` is now in the history of `main`, this command will return the hash of `y`.

One way to go around this is the one described above: when inspecting the history of `main`, only follow the leftmost path. This is as close as you will get, with `git`, for "the list of commits that were created directly on `main`".

Comment: pointing to an answer I wrote to another question: [How do I get a list of all git commits to a merged branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61617625/86072)