# Git - How to find actual commits done in specific git branch

Tags: git, version-control

I created a branch `t1` from `master` branch and made many commits in branch `t1`. 
Then I made several commits in other branches, merged other branches in `t1` etc.

Now I want to `find only those commits which I had made in branch t1` (not those commits which came from master branch or any other branch as result of merging)

Comment: If you merged the commits without creating merge commits, you can't really do this, except by examining the reflog and trying to infer where the commits came from. Branches aren't real things in Git, they're just named pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using a pull-request flow, there is not any reliable mechanism to record which commits are done for a specific branch.

The name of a local branch is allowed to be arbitrary. You can create a local branch `foo`, and push its new commits to the branch `bar`. If the push succeeds, we can only be sure the commits are made for `bar`. But it does not guarantee that the commits are made in a local `bar`. If you are allowed to directly push `foo` to `bar` without a pull-request, the system even doesn't have a permanent record that these commits are pushed to `bar`. You may find some clues in the commit message of a merge commit, but commit messages can be forged too, not to mention that you may not have strict format rules for commit messages. When the push is fast-forward, the merge commit itself does not even exist. The reflogs may have some clues too, but they are not reliable either as they are bound with local branches and not permanent.

With a systematic pull-request flow, the hosting services, like Github, Gerrit and Gitlab, have solid databases to record which commits are merged to a specific branch. They provide apis or interfaces, which allow users to retrieve these records from the databases.

In your case, you can try:

```
git log t1 ^master --first-parent --no-merges
```

But the result is not reliable in theory.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in "[Git: How to list commits on this branch but not from merged branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26596420/6309)", you can start with (using [`log --no-merges`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---no-merges)):

```
git log --no-merges t1 master
```

That would avoid any merge commit.

Comment: Unfortunately its not working, in t1 branch I made only one commit but it is displaying me many commits. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @D555 can you check the output of `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --branches`? See if you actually have only one commit between t1 HEAD and master.