# git - changes to branch since created?

Tags: git, branch, msysgit

I'm always asking myself a set of questions about branches i've created that i've yet to determine how to accomplish:

1. What files did i change in branch?
2. What are the actually changes (diff) i made to the branch?
3. What is the log of commits that i made to the branch?

Now i think if figured out how to get the hashes of all the commits that were committed to the branch but not merged into master using `git cherry master <branchname>`. With this i could go hash by hash and figure out everything but if you have a lot of commits this could be time consuming. Notice i'm not wanting to compare to current state of master. I think the key is knowing the hash of master that you created your branch off of but i'm not exactly sure how to determine this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649356/how-do-i-run-git-log-to-see-changes-only-for-a-specific-branch

Comment: @GabrielePetronella thanks that at least answers #3 i think.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To find where your current checkout diverged from the master branch,

```
base=`git merge-base master HEAD`
echo $base
```

to find out what files have been changed since then,

```
git diff --name-only $base HEAD
```

to show the accumulated difference

```
git diff $base HEAD
```

When you want to describe an entire series of commits you can use the syntax in the answer Gabriele Petronella linked above, `master..HEAD` is shorthand for `HEAD ^master` which means "all commits reachable from HEAD, but not including commits reachable from master".  Missing endpoints default to HEAD, so you can say `git log --oneline master..`

Comment: Thanks so much. Relatively new to git so i wasn't aware of the "merge-base" command. This answers my question perfectly.

Comment: Thanks! If you are using an external diff tool like [Beyond Compare](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2069490/266535), change the last line to `git difftool $base HEAD --dir`. It's useful when doing a code review of someone else's branch.

Answer (score 17):

Assuming you branched from `master`,

*1. What files have changed since branching?*

```
git diff master...<branchname> --name-only
```

*2. What is the full diff since branching?*

```
git diff master...<branchname>
```

*3. What is the commit log since branching?*

```
git log master..<branchname>
```

You do not need to specify `<branchname>` if you have it checked out (e.g., `git diff master...`).

**Note:** `git diff` requires triple dot `...` and `git log` requires double dot `..` to get the behavior that you are asking for.

---

For explanations on dot syntax, see:

- [... double-dot “..” and triple-dot “…” in Git commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-com)
- [... double-dot “..” and triple-dot “…” in Git **diff** commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-dif)
- [Pro Git - Commit Ranges](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges)

Comment: I prefer `git diff master... --stat` when I want to see a list of changed files.

Answer (score 2):

For the list of files changed and the actual diff, it makes more sense if you know 2 commits between which you wanna compare.

If you want to see the diff between `START_SHA1` and `END_SHA1`, you could do:

```
git diff START_SHA1 END_SHA1
```

If you want just the list of files, you could do:

```
git diff --name-only START_SHA1 END_SHA1
```

If you also want to know what type of change went into the file (like `A`, `M`, `D`, `C`, `R`, `U`), you could do:

```
git diff --name-status START_SHA1 END_SHA1
```