# Git: Get all notes of a branch

Tags: git, git-notes

We'd like to annotate our commits with `git notes add`, which works fine. To get a list of all commits with notes we use this command

```
git notes | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs -ihash git log hash -1
```

Now we are looking for the notes of a branch only. I'm at a loss here since the notes don't know anything about branches. May be there's a way to start with `git log` and ask `git notes` wheter there's a note for the commit. But I'm nut sure wheter this is to slow for big repositories.

Any ideas?

Comment: I see you use 'git log' in your command, according to this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649356/how-do-i-run-git-log-to-see-changes-only-for-a-specific-branch , maybe ( i'm not sure ) if you add your branch after ?? ex : 'git log mybranch' ??

Answer (score 4):

I would start with this:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H %N" --show-notes <branch>
```

See `git help log` for additional things you can put in the format string to fix up the output the way you want it...

Answer (score 1):

## finding notes

Show all abbreviated commits with notes for all commits on master that have notes:

```
git notes |\ 
  awk '{if (!system("git merge-base --is-ancestor "$2" master")) {print $2}}' |\
  xargs git show --abbrev-commit --oneline -s --notes
```

How does it work?

`git notes` lists a mapping of note blob to *target commit*:

```
$ git notes 
579c5b129af5662ca2ae6d08977fd5acfe4ca383 3c4f076572612726808d686d04acb2266401c2f9
63a79274ee3486213d58eef8a5a6f604f7c1fdb1 6546d605b21bb92f270af61f3cc00ff2978001e2
```

so you can filter the commits in your stream by testing each for branch membership.

But the cost of all those individual commands will really add up if you have a lot of notes.

## Per-branch notes

In future what you might want to do here is use different notes refs for different branches. I don't see a way to bind the `core.notesRef` configuration option to the current branch though, so you'd have to

```
git notes --ref "my-branch-name" --edit
```

etc. But you could probably

```
alias gn git notes --ref "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
```

to deal with that.

This won't sort your *current* notes by branch, but it'll help in future.

You'll need to configure the `refs/notes/branchname"` for each 
`branchname` to be fetched and pushed if you want to share them.