# git log of master branch when on a different branch

Tags: git

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649356/how-do-i-run-git-log-to-see-changes-only-for-a-specific-branch), I can use `git log master..my-branch` to see the log of commits to `my-branch`, assuming it was created off `master`, regardless of which branch I am on.  This is useful, but what if I want to see the log of all commits to `master`, back to the begging of time, while I have a different branch checked out?  `git log master..master` does nothing (understandably)

Comment: Maybe you need just `git log`?

Comment: @Hackerman that will give me the log of the current branch

Comment: Mmmm...try this one `git log --no-merges master..`

Comment: @Hackerman my master branch contains nothing but merge commits. That produces nothing, even when on the master branch

Comment: Aaah, my mistake...just remove the `--no-merges` option...it should be `git log  master..`

Comment: Does `git log master` not get you the history of `master`?

Comment: @sp0gg I don't know why that didn't seem to work before. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `git log master` should do the job.